# How to close webview image popup on back button press?

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a webview app where I'm displaying images in a full screen popup. But, whenever a user press back button, it goes to previous page without closing it. Where the user intent is to close the popup and view other images. If the pop-up is visible, how to stop going back to previous page, but close the pop up.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a function in your page which is loaded in WebView. When the back button is pressed, you call that function.
You can look at this link for more information:
[Calling JavaScript from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028496/calling-javascript-from-android)